# Saripaar formvalidation not working second time in kotlin

Tags: android, forms, validation, kotlin, saripaar

I am using [saripaar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) for form validation. I have some edittext in fragmentA, on validation success , view will be switched to fragmentB.
Butterknife and saripaar annotation in fragment.

```
@NotEmpty
@BindView(R.id.nameEditText)
lateinit var nameEditText: EditText
```

Saripaar initialization:

```
 val validator = Validator(this)
 validator.setValidationListener(this)
```

To validate the fields:

```
validator.validate()
```

Validation is working fine for the first time. When come back from fragmentB to fragmentA, then validation is not working, it will directly call onvalidationsuccess.

On **onValidationSucceeded** , I am using following function to switch to fragmentB.

```
fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val ft = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
    ft.addToBackStack(null)
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

This problem only appears in kotlin but not in java.

Comment: Post related code.

Comment: @azizbekian question updated with code.

Comment: Where from are you performing `validator.validate()`? Post fragment/activity also.

Comment: There is a submit button in fragmentA, On submit button click, I have validate the form i.e `validator.validate()`

Comment: I am using saripaar with kotlin project and it working fine for me. I think in your project it should be reference problem because for fragments. Can you provide any log ?

Comment: @RajeshDalsaniya Are you using with butterknife ? There is no error log or something like that. Can you share me buildtoolversion and support library version.

Comment: There is also an open issue on the project, but it's not yet fixed. You can track it here [https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/204] (https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/204)

Comment: @captaindroid buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" and implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'

Comment: I solved the issue, I have all the saripaar initialization in basefragment,I was checking the validator instance like:
`if(validator==null){
 validator = Validator(this)
 validator.setValidationListener(this)
}`
     
I removed the null check part and its now working. Thanks guys @azizbekian @Rajesh @Rinav

Comment: Had you been generous enough and shared proper code - you'd have had solved your problem way sooner ;-)

Comment: Yes, stupid me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue, I have all the saripaar initialization in basefragment, I have the following code in basefragment with null check for validator instance:

```
if(validator==null){  
 validator = Validator(this) 
 validator.setValidationListener(this) 
}
```

As I removed the null check part, now its working fine.

```
validator = Validator(this) 
validator.setValidationListener(this)
```